# RESTful Routing - Header Authorization in APIs

Tags: rest

In the context of an API, if you're using `Authorization Header` tokens to authenticate the user on each request, then how do you go about setting up RESTful routes which would otherwise use the 'User ID' in the URL request?

example:

`POST /api/school/5/user`

Adds User to School

`DELETE /api/school/5/user/???`
Removes User from School

However, the DELETE request would require the User ID in the request, which if you're using a `Bearer Authorization` token, wouldn't be passed in the URL, which then makes those sorts of Resources difficult to setup.

How is this handled generally?

Comment: How is Authorization header related to resource id? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Kamil it isn't  However a User could be a resource model (or sub resource).  But if the the current user is being retrieved via an authorization token, and you wanted to make a restful which involved that User, it seems that would be difficult because you aren't passing the user the via the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solutions I found for this are:

1) You can pass the User ID via the URL but just compare it to the User ID of the User retrieved from the Authorization Token.  So you might have a URL like:

`/api/school/5/user/7`

And in you Middleware, check that that User in your Authorization Heaer, matches the User passed via the URL.  This way you maintain RESTful routing.

OR

2) Alter the URL structure some and have a `Me` route prefix.  So any routes that are based around the logged in User, should be prefixed with `Me` (or similar).  Spotify, Facebook, and many other companies' APIs use this.

I prefer it to the first solution because even though the first seems more standard, the idea of passing a user's ID in URL unnecessarily seems less than ideal.